# Gráfico dinâmico não atualiza

Tags: php, javascript, html, angularjs, canvas

Estou usando a biblioteca [RGraph](https://www.rgraph.net/demos/svg-line-dynamic.html) de gráficos *HTML5*, e deveria atualizar dinamicamente junto com o banco.

Porém, gostaria que no gráfico fosse colocado o ultimo dado imputado no banco, portanto, se eu inserisse o valor 10 no banco, a linha do gráfico iria ficar em 10 até eu inserir outro valor, como 25, e o gráfico daria um salto.

Porém o gráfico não está dando esse salto imediato, caso o ultimo valor seja 10, e eu inputo 25, ele se mantem em 10 a não ser que eu atualize a página.

Segue o trecho do código:

```
function update ()
{
    // A global

    l$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "consulta.php",
        data: {},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (last)
        {
            line.originalData[0].push(last);
            line.originalData[0].shift();
            RGraph.SVG.redraw();
        }
    });
    setTimeout(function () { update() }, 50);
}
update();
```

Arquivo consulta.php:

```
<?php 
 include("salvateste.php");
 $execute_again = mysqli_query($conexao, "Select * FROM tabelapi order by Evento desc"); 
 $lone = mysqli_fetch_object($execute_again); 
 $mostra_tudao[0] = $lone->Amperes; 
 echo json_encode($mostra_tudao[0]);
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso está acontecendo porque o código PHP que está no mesmo arquivo que renderiza o gráfico, o PHP é processado apenas uma vez no momento do carregamento da página, então para processar repetidas vezes, é necessário chamar repetidas vezes.

A solução pro seu problema é uma requisição ajax que traga os dados, de forma simples, defina um setInterval que faça um requisição a cada X segundos, e preencha o gráfico com esses dados:

A função:

```
function update ()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "consulta.php",
        data: {},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (last)
        {
             line.originalData[0].push(last);
             line.originalData[0].shift();
             RGraph.SVG.redraw();
        }
    });
}
```

O arquivo PHP que devolve o número:

```
<?php 
$execute_again = mysqli_query($conexao, "Select * FROM tabelapi order by Evento desc"); 
$lone = mysqli_fetch_object($execute_again); 
$mostra_tudao[$i] = $lone->Amperes; 
echo json_encode($mostra_tudao);
?>
```

E o no arquivo onde renderiza o gráfico, ao fim do arquivo, adicione um setInterval chamando a função (deixei 1 segundo, o tempo tanto faz, mas não deixe muito rapido pois é desnecessário):

```
 setTimeout(function () { update() }, 1000);
```

Comment: Na linha  line.originalData[0].push(last);
Que valor que vai ao invés do last?

Comment: Na verdade eu havia colocado erradom, corrigi a respota ja da uma olhada na atualização, você devolve last dentro da function. mudou uma palvra só, de function(line) para function(last).

Comment: Eu fiz as mudanças que você sugeriu, mesmo assim, nada acontece, agora o gráfico não plota nada, estou fazendo algo errado?

Arquivo consulta.php
<?php 
include("salvateste.php");
$execute_again = mysqli_query($conexao, "Select * FROM tabelapi order by Evento desc"); 
$lone = mysqli_fetch_object($execute_again); 
$mostra_tudao[0] = $lone->Amperes; 
echo json_encode($mostra_tudao[0]);
?>

Comment: Função update:


function update ()
    {
        // A global


        l$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "consulta.php",
        data: {},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (last)
        {
             line.originalData[0].push(last);
             line.originalData[0].shift();
             RGraph.SVG.redraw();
        }
            });
        setTimeout(function () { update() }, 50);
    }
        

    update();

Comment: @FelipeRodrigues atualiza a pergunta com o código que está usando agora formatado, fica muito ruim de ler aqui no comentário

Comment: Atualizei, consegue perceber algum erro no código?

Comment: De um console.log(last) dentro de success:function(last){} e veja se o resultado é apenas um número, outra observação, você deve renderizar o gráfico com  função draw do plugin antes de executar updates: https://www.rgraph.net/demos/svg-line-dynamic.html

Comment: Coloquei o console.log(last) e continuou me retornando o grafico vazio, desabilitei as outras funções e nada ocorreu, essa segunda coisa que você me falou pra fazer eu não entendi muito bem.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67970/discussion-between-anthraxisbr-and-felipe-rodrigues).